# How to stringify object which returned from elastic search DB to display in grafana table?

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, jaeger

I'm using grafana dashboard to display elastic search (jeager logs data) json data as table format.
But some columns showing [object object] rows. I could resolve this by change cell display mode to JSON view but while I'm try to filter it's shows [object object] value.
Is there any way to stringify [Column Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNzJD.png)object?